# Not able to see entries in Sent items of docusign application

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the embedded signing feature of DocuSign and I have integrated my application with DocuSign. I am using the SOBO functionality to create envelopes.

I am able to generate the URL and able to send it also. User also getting the envelope but when I login to my DocuSign account, I don't see the entries in sent items.

Please help me to understand what can be the issue here.If we leverage the SOBO functionality why can't we see the entries in Sent items?

Comment: Maybe contact docu sign technical support?

Comment: currently i am using the demo account and am not sure docusign provide technical support for demo.if they provide can anyone share me the details how to connect with them

Answer (score 0):

If the signer is receiving the envelope, then you're sending it correctly.

In that case, if you're using SOBO, then the user that you're sending the envelope for should see it in *her* Sent items list, not in yours.

Eg, "System account 01" is an authorized SOBO user. It sends an envelope on behalf of Susan. Susan should see the envelope in her sent items list. And Susan should receive email notifications when the signer signs the documents, when the envelope is completed, etc.